# Does this data structure have a name? Sort of a "linked matrix"?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures

Let's say I wanted similar functionality to a doubly linked list but needed a matrix instead so that each node was structured like this:

```
public class Node
{
    Node Up, Down, Left, Right;
    object Value;
}
```

Is there a name for such a structure? I've looked through this [Wikipedia listing of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) but didn't see anything similar. Unless I just missed it.

Comment: I read this and inmediately thought of http://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: Knuth's Dancing Links (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) uses a similiar structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data structure is sometimes called a *mesh*.  The representation you have shown here is a species of **directed graph**.

Comment: @MPelletier: I think that clusterf*ck could catch up.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any resources to point to? From what I can tell in searching online: in a mesh structure the node represents an edge?

Comment: @Tom: Only if a single node is known as a clusterf*cklet.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply linked list.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: Or my personnal favourite, clusterf*ck.